# Angular 2 beta.8 How to use @Query?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use `@Query` to get some information about an element in my template. But I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried doing it this way: [Documented here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html) Mine looks like this,

```
import {Component, Query, QueryList, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector : 'my-app',
    template : `
        <banner #banner>
            <h4>Some New App</h4>
        </banner>
        <div class="container"></div>
    `
})

export class App
{
    private banner:any;

    constructor(@Query('banner') banner:QueryList<ElementRef>)
    {
        this.banner = banner;
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log(this.banner)
    }
}
```

**Console log shows this:**

[image]

Now I could be wrong here. But I would expect `_results: Array[0]` to have one result. I would expect it to contain some information about the `<h4>` element.

So with that in mind. I tried doing it a few different ways following the documentation. I have seen some people using kabob case, some with camel, ect. So I thought maybe the docs haven't been updated.

After more searching I came across this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3922

Has `@Query` been changed to this syntax?

`@ContentChild()` and `@ViewChildren()`

Either way my question is what is the correct way to do this as of today? Or am just completely missing something here?

Comment: is `banner` is another component?

Comment: @PankajParkar, Not at the moment. But it probably will be eventually. I am just trying to figure out the separate pieces of what Angular has to offer at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Query` is the equivalent of `@ContentChild/@ContentChildren` (elements projected through `ng-content`) therefore it won't work to query for elements inside your view. The one you want is `@ViewQuery()`. That said, you better not use `@Query` nor `@ViewQuery` since this [API will be removed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4919).

This is your code corrected

```js
import {Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector : 'my-app',
    template : `
        <banner #banner>
            <h4>Some New App</h4>
        </banner>
        <div class="container"></div>
    `
})
export class App {

    @ViewChildren('banner') banner: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.banner)
    }
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JfzOxSxjlqG6yxJcBoZF?p=preview) with your example working with the current API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This clears things up. I actually had tried @ViewQuery also.. that didn't work either. Also it may not matter. But out of curiosity.  Is there a way to get this info in the `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook? Or does it only work in `ngAfterViewInit()`?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck as stated in the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) docs, `@ViewChild/@ViewChildren` are set by the time `ngAfterViewInit` is called. Your code with `@ViewQuery` works fine, but in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Okay, I must have missed that part. Thanks for helping